# What is the correct syntax of my update button?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How can I insert the Out to my TimeSheet? I insert some data and hes IN then my problem is how can I insert out from him but my database syntax is incorrect.

I am unsure of the logic.

```
       if (label2.Text != "")
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update Attendance set empOut=@empOut where Date=@Date && Name=@Name)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@empOut", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(label1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label3.Text;
            execnonquery(cmd, "Data Inserted");
            label2.Text = "";
            label3.Text = "";
            label4.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: change `&&` to `AND`

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Remove the closing parenthesis at the end of the SQL; Instead of `&&` use `AND` from the SQL (yes `&&` is accepted by MySQL yet `AND` is more "standard"); `Dispose()` the `MySqlCommand` at the end or wrap a `using()` around the code; `execnonquery()` is some method you wrote? Do you really want to get text from labels, as the names suggest, or rather from text boxes?

Comment: it worked hahaha thank you guys @ZoharPeled